# Does the current or voltage switch when an inductance goes from being a load to a source?

Tags: inductance, coil

[image]

When first S1 is closed to charge the coil the voltage UL and current IL are inline and positive. When the switch S2 closes and S1 opens, does the current or voltage switch direction?

Comment: Current continues to flow same direction, voltage is reversed.

Comment: The current stays flowing as it was before, the voltage changes abruptly in whatever way it needs to, to allow the current to keep flowing. The new voltage then makes the current ramp steadily to a different value.

Comment: @Neil_UK, It's an exponential decay to zero, rather than a ramp.

Comment: @Chu did I say anything about the shape of the ramp, I didn't use the word 'linear' in there? I used 'ramp steadily' in distinction to 'abruptly', which is how the voltage changes. The 'voltage makes the current ramp' implies that the rate of ramp is dependent on the voltage, which is of course changing as the current changes. Perhaps 'change steadily' might have been a better choice.

Comment: @Neil_UK *Ramp*, in reference to signals and systems, is normally taken as meaning a function with a constant gradient, starting at \$t=0\$.